# Android USB Gadget Non-Host Mode Examples

Tags: android, usb

Are there any examples of how to use Gadget modes on Android, particularly any that don't require rooting my device?  I am hoping to be able to communicate upstream to a host PC. Almost all the documents and examples I can find online describe how to use Android as the host, but that's the opposite of what I am after.

I understand that Accessory mode exists, however, it is not available on all platforms.

I am just looking for some help finding content/information about how to use Android in non-host-mode.

What keywords am I missing?  Is there a well understood mechanism to allow apps to communicate with a host PC (with libusb or other custom drivers) without developer access? Does anyone have any examples?